How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
How to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for  javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
I am using Java 17 and Spring boot 3.
I am getting this error :
Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
This issue I am getting while retrieving the jet token.
These are the dependency I am using.
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

Now when I am fetching the response from login I want authorization should get passed to frontend so that it can be used for further calls.
So in my login service, I am calling like
@Override
public LoginResponseDTO authenticateUser(LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDTO) {
    Optional<Users> userOptional = repository.findByEmail(loginRequestDTO.getEmail());

    Users user = userOptional.get();
    String token = generateToken(user.getEmail());
 ………………..

This is my jwtUtil class :
@Component
public class JwtUtil {

    private String secret = "your_secret_key"; 

    public String generateToken(String username) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret)
                .compact();
    }

    public Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token, String username) {
        return (username.equals(extractUsername(token)) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractAllClaims(token).getSubject();
    }

    public boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractAllClaims(token).getExpiration().before(new Date());
    }
}

This is my SecurityConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                                .requestMatchers("/api/user/validate").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                                   )
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "customJwtAuthenticationFilter")
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
 @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

And also this is my JwtAuthenticationFilter
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;

        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails.getUsername())) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here and what u need to do to fix this issue.

Spring Boot 3 uses jakarta instead of the the old javax classes, so it seems one of the dependencies you're using is out of date and still looking for the old javax.xml.bind.* classes.

You need to add jaxb-api library because jjwt library still uses the older JAXB library.
Please add the above library dependency in the build.gradle:
dependencies {
   .....
   implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
}

It will work.
